# Postgresql Upgrade from 9.1.9 to 9.4.5 pg_stat_activity.procpid causes failure

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

Attempting to upgrade from 9.1.9 to 9.4.5 Postgresql.

`pg_upgrade` process fails while trying to `pg_restore` `pg_stat_activity`. This fails because the column name differs from the old system to the new system.

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 498; 1259 26457 VIEW blocking_procs postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  column a.procpid does not exist
LINE 14: ...bl" JOIN "pg_stat_activity" "a" ON (("bl"."pid" = "a"."procp...
```

How does one solve this issue and use `pg_upgrade` to move from 9.1.9 to 9.4.5?

Comment: It's not `pg_stat_activity` that fails in restore, it's `blocking_procs`. Issue `drop view blocking_procs` in 9.1

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you have a view, `blocking_procs` on top of `pg_stat_activity`.  You will need to drop that view and reinstall it after the upgrade.

```
DROP VIEW blocking_procs;
```

Comment: Not sure how to drop that view. Attempted to do it and the system returns the following: postgres=# drop view pg_stat_activity;
ERROR:  permission denied: "pg_stat_activity" is a system catalog

Comment: I figured it out... allow_system_table_mods needed to be turned on.

Comment: ... actually... was able to drop the view. But pg_upgrade fails with the original error message.

Comment: The view you need to drop is called `blocking_procs`.

Comment: @AdminTPG can you mark this answer as chosen if it works for you?